# Symfony 3 после переустановки open server в dev режиме не находит файлы стилей

Tags: symfony, openserver

Symfony 3 после переустановки open server в dev режиме не находит файлы стилей
ищет в папке /app_dev.php/css* но папка как бы пустая. В prod все нормально. 
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
php bin/console assetic:dump
эти команды не помогли. Проект залит на боевой и там дев работает нормально. На локальном такая проблема на всех проектах. 
что это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только связка Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.6 работает корректно